# What is the use of implementing runnable in mainactivity

Tags: android, runnable

Recently, I am studying a code about printer Bluetooth connection.
The program try implement runnable in the MainActivity.
Here I would like to ask 2 question.
1.How can I execute the activity as a thread when there is no other program calling run() of this activity?
2.Is there any special meaning for implementing runnable in MainActivity? Are ther any difference between implementing runnable in a class other than MainActivity?

Comment: `How can I execute the activity as a thread`. You can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not too certain what you are asking in the first question because code inside Activity will always run on the main (UI) thread by default.

To answer your second question, the MainActivity is probably implementing the Runnable interface only to define some code that can be executed on a Thread later.

For example, you can call [runOnUiThread (Runnable action)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) from the Activity, passing MainActivity.this as the runnable parameter to execute code on the main thread.

You can also spawn a new thread with the runnable to have it run in the background or post it to a handler.

Comment: Thank you, Endor. For my first question, I am asking whether there is some way to run the main activity as a thread but not a main (UI)thread?

Comment: I see. Just as Pedro said in his/her comment, you can't. You can spawn a new thread to run code on its own, but the main thread will always be present.

Comment: Thank you, Endor. So the code should be called by other activities if its mainactivity implemented runnable. Am I right?

Comment: I think a Runnable should only be used within the Activity that defines it. If you want to define tasks to be launched from multiple Activities, you should use a Service.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sequence of callback methods that start up an activity and a sequence of callback methods that tear down an activity.
1)Created 2)Started 3)Resumed 4) Paused 5) Stopped 6)Destroyed
However, only three of these states can be static :-3)Resumed 4) Paused 5) Stopped,,,,
Resumed State(Running state):- In this state, the activity is in the foreground and the user can interact with it.
 (Also sometimes referred to as the "running" state.)

here are simply two rules to Android's single thread model:
    1) Do not block the UI thread
    2)Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread